# Adding Assumptions in double integral written in "math input" mode

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax, assumptions, education

I've the following double integral and I'd like to write Assumptions->Re[c]>0, but if I try to do it, I get a syntax error. How can I add the above condition but without changing the visualization of the integral (see figure below)?

```
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-\[Infinity]\), \
\(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-\[Infinity]\), \(\[Infinity]\)]
\*FractionBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\), \(2*Sqrt[8*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(c\), \(2\)] - 2*c - 1]\)]*Exp[\(-
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]\)*
\*FractionBox[\(9*c*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + c*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)] - 2*\((c + 1)\)*x*y\), \(8*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(c\), \(2\)] - 2*c - 
       1\)]] \[DifferentialD]y \[DifferentialD]x\)\)
```

[image]

---

EDIT: I'd like to use the syntax in the above code.

Comment: How about setting `$Assumptions` instead?

Comment: Append[unevaluated[…integral…,], Assumptions-> …] ?

Comment: If this question is about [tag:output-formatting] or input formatting, then `Integrate[]` is defined to be typeset/input with traditional integral signs only when there are no `Assumptions` or other options.  You could probably use the `Notation` package.

Answer (score 0):

Does "HoldForm" what you want?

```
HoldForm@Integrate[(x^2*y^2)/(2*Sqrt[8*c^2 - 2*c - 1])*
   Exp[-(1/2)*(9*c*x^2 + c*y^2 - 2*(c + 1)*x*y)/(
     8*c^2 - 2*c - 1)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}, Assumptions -> Re[c] > 0]
```

[image]

**Update**

If you only want the visual output without a valid MMA expression, you can try:

```
Row[{HoldForm[
   Integrate[(x^2*y^2)/(2*Sqrt[8*c^2 - 2*c - 1])*
     Exp[-(1/2)*(9*c*x^2 + c*y^2 - 2*(c + 1)*x*y)/(8*c^2 - 2*c - 
          1)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]], 
  "," Assumptions -> Re[c] > 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @DanielHuber thank you for your answer. If possible I'd like to see also the two integral symbols.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi - Use `Assuming` rather than `Assumptions`, i.e., `HoldForm@Assuming[Re[c] > 0, Integrate[(x^2*y^2)/(2*Sqrt[8*c^2 - 2*c - 1])*Exp[-(1/2)*(9*c*x^2 + c*y^2 - 2*(c + 1)*x*y)/(8*c^2 - 2*c - 1)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]] // TraditionalForm` or `HoldForm@ConditionalExpression[Integrate[(x^2*y^2)/(2*Sqrt[8*c^2 - 2*c - 1])*Exp[-(1/2)*(9*c*x^2 + c*y^2 - 2*(c + 1)*x*y)/(8*c^2 - 2*c - 1)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}], Re[c] > 0] // TraditionalForm`

Comment: Hello @BobHanlon I appreciate your comment. I need to use the syntax in the code of my answer instead of the classical one.

Comment: I added a form with integral sign, however, this can not be evaluated.

Comment: Hi @DanielHuber I need to write the input as in the figure I posted, not in the form Integrate[]